# Equivalent of javascript reduce in R

Tags: javascript, r

In javascript, I can reduce an array of data to a single value. For example, if I want to find how many points in an array are within some euclidean distance from (4,3), I can do this:

```
var x = 4;
var y = 3;

var howManyPointsAreWithinRange = a.reduce( (pd, d) => {
    var xp = d.weight;
    var yp = d.total;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - xp) + Math.pow(y - yp));
    if (distance < 10) {
        return pd + 1;
    }

    return pd;
}, 0);
```

In R, I have tried aggregate functions, the apply family and dplyr, but all suppose that you want to group results by some variable. How can I achieve the same functionality of `reduce()` in R?.

My version of R doesn't support the funprog package.

Comment: You can use summarise in dplyr without a group_by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most R operators and functions work with vectors, so you can do something like:

```
d <- data.frame(weight=c(1:10), total=c(11:20))
   weight total
1       1    11
2       2    12
3       3    13
4       4    14
5       5    15
6       6    16
7       7    17
8       8    18
9       9    19
10     10    20

x<-4
y <- 3

x-d$weight
 [1]  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6

(x-d$weight)^2
 [1]  9  4  1  0  1  4  9 16 25 36

sqrt((x-d$weight)^2+(y-d$total)^2)
 [1]  8.544004  9.219544 10.049876 11.000000 12.041595 13.152946 14.317821 15.524175 16.763055 18.027756
```

Then to count the number of items who match your condition, you count the number of condition being `TRUE`(=1) by summing:

```
sum(sqrt((x-d$weight)^2+(y-d$total)^2)<10)
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`reduce()` is a base function in JavaScript that simply applies a function successively to all elements of an array.  If you'd like to replicate that functionality in R, you could use:

```
reduce <- function(arr,fun,start) {
    current <- start
    for (i in 1:length(arr)) {
        current <- fun(current,arr[i])
    }
    current
}
```

This replicates the functionality of JS' `reduce`, which can be useful if you need a general-purpose, flexible method of reduction using different, complex functions.  However, R is cool in that it treats many functions this way *anyway*; for example, `sum(arr)` works the same as `reduce(arr,sum,0)` from above.  So it may be worth examining whether the functionality you need already exists in base R.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I think it is `Reduce`